# Move Values of a dataframe to a list based on a condition

Tags: python, list, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements

I am trying to move the data from a single column in a dataframe to a list.

```
Account Name    Renewal % Change
Client 1        0%
Client 2        0%
Client 3        2%
Client 4        0%
Client 5        1%
Client 6        1%
```

So If a client has 0% It should get added to the list Cost0 and it it has 1% it should get added to Cost1.

I tried using a pd.series.tolist() but it kept giving me an error.

```
if brl['Renewal % Change'] == '0%':
    a = pd.Series(brl['Account Name'])
    a.tolist()
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Please advise

Comment: I can't check it right now, but isn't it a `if` statement that you are getting the error from?

Try something like that:


list1 = brl.loc[brl['Renewal % Change'] == '0%', 'Account Name'].tolist()

list2 = brl.loc[brl['Renewal % Change'] == '1%', 'Account Name'].tolist()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Cost0 = brl[blr['Renewal % Change']=='0%']['Account Name'].tolist()
Cost1 = brl[blr['Renewal % Change']=='1%']['Account Name'].tolist()
```

**Update**

Using `.loc`

```
Cost0 = brl.loc[blr['Renewal % Change']=='0%','Account Name'].tolist()
Cost1 = brl.loc[blr['Renewal % Change']=='1%','Account Name'].tolist()
```

Comment: Thank you this is simple solution and works just how I wanted

Answer (score 2):

You can use a bit changed [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with selecting column by `loc`:

```
mask = brl['Renewal % Change'] == '0%'
print (mask)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: Renewal % Change, dtype: bool

print (brl.loc[mask, 'Account Name'].tolist())
['Client 1', 'Client 2', 'Client 4']
```

All together:

```
Cost0 = brl.loc[brl['Renewal % Change'] == '0%', 'Account Name'].tolist()
print (Cost0)
['Client 1', 'Client 2', 'Client 4']

Cost1 = brl.loc[brl['Renewal % Change'] == '1%', 'Account Name'].tolist()
print (Cost1)
['Client 5', 'Client 6']
```

---

You get error, because comparing return boolean `Series` - array, not scalar value, see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas):

```
print (brl['Renewal % Change'] == '0%')
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: Renewal % Change, dtype: bool
```

Comparing solutions - with `loc` is faster:

```
In [137]: %timeit brl.loc[brl['Renewal % Change'] == '0%', 'Account Name'].tolist()
1000 loops, best of 3: 536 µs per loop

In [138]: %timeit brl[brl['Renewal % Change']=='0%']['Account Name'].tolist()
1000 loops, best of 3: 657 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks the 2nd solution worked fine and also for giving the reason on the error So this means IF condition on Pandas data frame wont work fine

Comment: exactly, if in pandas is used rare, because `Series`, `DataFrames` and `Panels` use arrays.

Comment: So using them within the same braces uses a shorter time I assume

Comment: I think there is difference another solution use pure `boolean indexing` and my answer use select and boolean indexing together. So my solution is faster and it means obviously better. So I hope my answer will be accepted. But if like another solution, then it is OK.